# How to add mysql connector to Sqoop 1.99.3

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, bigdata, sqoop

I have installed Hadoop & connected with Hadoop locally successful. I can connect the Sqoop via REST api and via cli interface.

But once I want to start creating a job for important data from MySQL. It shows

> Connection configuration Warning message: Can't connect to the
>   database with given credentials: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/for
>
> Error message: Can't load specified driver

after google its solution, I has already

- put the mysql-connector.jar to `sqoop` web lib folder
- create a `lib` folder under the sqoop folder and put the mysql-connector.jar in it

I also have restarted or even reboot my VM. It still says cannot load specified driver.

Is there any config files I have missed to set? Thank you!

My ENV:

- VirtualBox + Vagrant + Ubuntu 12.04
- JDK (Sun Distrubution 1.7_update 51)
- Hadoop 2.2.0 (complied version)
- Sqoop 1.99.3  (complied version)

Thank again!

Comment: Download JDBC Connector from [https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), extract it and put the driver’s jar into sqoop's lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

check your 'JDBC Driver Class' of the connection you just created in sqoop,it should be setted
as `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.
If still not work,put mysql-connector-java-3.1.12-bin.jar into `$SQOOP_HOME/server/lib`